# max REST URI supported by Apache httpd

Tags: linux, apache, rest, uri, max

I'm chasing this problem where my REST client (curl) program is sending a very long URI(5000 chars) to my Apache httpd 2.2.15 (RHEL6) which is being denied. From the Apache docs, i read that default max. URI length supported is 8190 (via LimitRequestLine [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#limitrequestline)), but when I'm giving a URI of 5000 chars (like somehost/dir1/dir2/dir3/.../dir700/ ), i'm getting this error in ssl_error_log file:

```
[Tue Apr 02 17:29:16 2013] [error] [client 10.0.100.1] (36)File name too long: Cannot map GET <<long URI>> HTTP/1.1 to file
```

From the apache code, this looks to be hitting the PATH_MAX(4096) limit of Linux. If this is the case, then how can I make sure that URI are honoured up to 8190 chars? OR else is there any other limit which restricts the path to 4096 chars?